Getting a error trying to connect to SharePoint with CSOM
I am currently trying to make a connection to my Microsoft SharePoint site through C#. I'm using the microsoft.sharepoint.client.online.csom\15.0.4919.1000 library and I'm not having success...
Can you help me?
I made a small console application to test and this was the code I tested.
static async void CheckConnection()
{
    var passTask = GetUserPasswordAsync();
    string userID = <username>;

    using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://<company_sharepoint>.sharepoint.com/sites/<my_site>"))
    {
        await passTask;
        if (passTask.Result is null)
            return;
        SharePointOnlineCredentials credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userID, passTask.Result);
        ctx.Credentials = credentials;
        Web myWeb = ctx.Web;
        ctx.Load(myWeb, w => w.Title);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(myWeb.Title);
    }
}

But whenever I run the line of code
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
It throws the error
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.IdcrlException: 'Identity Client Runtime Library (IDCRL) did not get a response from the Login server.'
I don't know exactly what's going on or if I'm using the correct library or method...
Can anyone help me?
